# I've a json object which is not bear a proper characteristic for json key, so how can formatted proper key for this json object

Tags: json, flutter, dart, object

{
"language": {
"blogs details": "blogs details",
"Search products": "Search products",
"Somethings went wrong": "Somethings went wrong",
"Become seller": "Become seller",
"Cart": "Cart",
"Your name": "Your Name",
"Checkout": "Checkout"
}
}

## I'm Expecting like this

{
"language": {
"blogs_details": "blogs details",
"search_products": "Search products",
"Somethings_went_wrong": "Somethings went wrong",
"become_seller": "Become seller",
"cart": "Cart",
"your_name": "Your Name",
"checkout": "Checkout"
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map data = {
  "blogs details": "blogs details",
  "Somethings went wrong": "Somethings went wrong",
  "Cart": "Cart",
};
Map newMap = {};
data.forEach((key, value) {
  if (key.contains(' ')) {
    var newKey = key.toString().replaceAll(' ', '_').toLowerCase();
    newMap[newKey] = value;
  } else {
    var newKey = key.toString().toLowerCase();
    newMap[newKey] = value;
  }
});
print('newMap: ${newMap}');
```

Comment: I think is not useful for nested json data